Asymptotic[] disagrees with numerics
I have defined the following expression by integration followed by substition.
integraln  = 2*Integrate[Exp[-u]*u^(n - 1)/Sqrt[u^2 - y^2],
{u,y,Infinity},
Assumptions->y>0&&Element[n,Integers]&&n<0
]
regulateddiff = ((integraln/.{n->-3+epsilon}) +(integraln/.{n->-2+epsilon}))/.{y->1};

Here $\epsilon$ is a regulator I'd like to take to 0. I have a formal argument that this should work, and mumerics confirm this. For example,
N[regulateddiff/.{epsilon->0.00001}]

returns .9008131, and converges as epsilon shrinks. But when I ask Mathematica for the actual asymptotic form
N[Asymptotic[regulateddiff,epsilon->0]]

it returns 0.257076/epsilon which of course diverges as $\epsilon \to 0$. Is this a known bug? Is there some best practice (or simply a PEBCAC issue) I'm missing?

regulateddiff =   MeijerG[{{}, {5/2}}, {{0, 1/2, 2}, {}}, 1/4] +    MeijerG[{{}, {2}}, {{0, 1/2, 3/2}, {}}, 1/4] :)

Don't see any problem: N[regulateddiff /. {epsilon -> 0.00000000001}, 20] returns 2943.85.

@MariuszIwaniuk how did you manage that simplification? Do you mean that that's the exactly limit of regulateddiff as $\epsilon \to 0$? That's of course what I'm really after (or more exactly, I'm after that for more general values of $y$).
